# Using kivy urlrequest behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, kivy, urlrequest

I just want to use the kivy urlrequest behind a proxy, but it seems that doesn't care of my environment variables. Is there any way to use it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `UrlRequest` uses httplib interally which does not directly support proxying. You can use urllib which transparently supports proxies, or use httplib and manually proxy the request yourself.

Please submit a bug report for this at https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues.